# How to balance the readwrite conflict in Android Camera subsytem？

Tags: android, algorithm, optimization, android-camera

There are some buffers to store the data getting from the Camera Sensor in Android Camera HAL. The upper layer will copy the data **one by one** to do some special things.

Frame per second (FPS) is the handle speed in upper layer. **I must ensure the fps as large as possible!**, since the good user experience.

However, writing into the buffer is faster than reading by upper layer. Is there any way to balance the conflict?